# Fast MAX, GROUP BY on the concatenation of mulliple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table with 4 columns: name, date, version,and value. There's an composite index on all four, in that order. It has 20M rows: 2.000 names, approx 1.000 dates per name, approx 10 versions per date.

I'm trying to get a list that give for all names the highest date, the highest version on that date, and the associated value.

When I do

```
  SELECT name,
         MAX(date) 
    FROM table 
GROUP BY name
```

I get good performance and the database uses the composite index

However, when I join the table to this in order to get the `MAX(version)` per name the query takes ages. There must be a way to get the result in about the same magnitude of time as the SELECT statement above? I can easily be done by using the index.

Comment: Can you show us the JOIN query that's so slow, too?

Comment: "M" means million?  Some North Americans won't be aware that the period goes in place of commas in other countries formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  (I know it needs a few syntax tweaks for MySQL... ask for them and I will find them)

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT name, MAX(Date) as Date
FROM table
Group By name

select table.name, table.date, max(table.version) as version
from table
inner join #TempTable on table.name = #temptable.name and table.date = #temptable.date
group by table.name, table.date
```

Comment: Thanks,I tweaked and tried it. The filling of the temp table takes 0.06sec, the second query 20sec. That basically the same performance I get with subqueries instead of temporary tables.

Comment: Update: it turns out that it was using a wrong (test) index. removing the index made it use the correct composite index, and than improved the query time from 20sec to 0.04sec.